# Use contextual filter global null to pass values to override field result

Tags: 7, commerce, views

I come again with new question about Drupal Views and i hope you can help and explain me how to achieve this, I made a page view to display all my content (this works fine) with the following path:

`/car/%/%/%`

Now I want to get all the aliases of that path, for example: `/car/2009/vw/jetta` and then get `%1=2009`, `%2=vw`, `%3=jetta` and then use this to rewrite the output of a field to show something like this:

`<a href="/details/%1/%2/%3"> [name]</a>`,

and with this get my URL like: `/details/2009/vw/jetta`

I see that maybe this is possible with contextual filter: `global: null`. I tried to configure it but i only get the URL with tid's (`/details/10/25/33`) instead of the alias.

Can you explain me how can I configure `global:null` to get the values that i want without affecting my view results?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while but i solved this problem with something like this:

Added 3 Global: Null context filters and then i configured them with something like this:

For global 1:
WHEN FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL>>Provide default value>>Type:RAW value from URL>> Path Component: 1 >> Checked Use Path Alias >> Apply changes

For global 2:
WHEN FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL>>Provide default value>>Type:RAW value from URL>> Path Component: 2 >> Checked Use Path Alias >> Apply changes

For global 3:
WHEN FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL>>Provide default value>>Type:RAW value from URL>> Path Component: 3 >> Checked Use Path Alias >> Apply changes

And with that you can get the values to use them when you want to override a field output using contextual filter values.